# javascript not working - $ is not defined problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im fighting with this all day, searching on google and on stackoverflow but cant get it why is this working:

```
<head>

    <script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       $('input:radio[name="RADIOSELECTOR"]').change(function() {

            if ($(this).val()=='one') {
                    $('#ones').removeAttr('disabled');
                 $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
            } else if ($(this).val()=='two') {
                $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                 $('#twos').removeAttr('disabled');
            }  else  {
              $('#ones').attr('disabled',true);
                      $('#twos').attr('disabled',true);
             }


                         });

       </script>
    </head>
    <form name="order" action="managecart.html" onsubmit="return AddToCart(this); return ValidateCart(this);">
    <input name="PRICE" type=hidden id="PRICE" value="" />
    <input name=NAME type=hidden id="NAME" value="" />
    <input name=ID_NUM type=hidden id="ID_NUM" value="" />
    <input type=hidden name="SHIPPING" value="0.00" />
    <input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='59.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitiazer replacement'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGL'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer repair  <b>59.99$</b><br><br>
    <b> Combo repairs:</b><BR><br>
    <input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="lose" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='74.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + battery repair'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLB'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery repair = <b> 74.99$</b> 25$ in savings!<br>

    <input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="one" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='79.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo '; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + <select id="ones" name="ADDITIONALINFO2" disabled="disabled">
    <option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select>

     = <b>79.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

    <input type="radio" name="RADIOSELECTOR" value="two" onClick="document.order.PRICE.value='99.99'; document.order.NAME.value='iPhone 3G Glass/digitizer + combo + ''ADDITIONALINFO3'; document.order.ID_NUM.value='3GGLBC'; document.order.SHIPPING.value='0.00';" />Glass/digitizer + battery +  <select name="ADDITIONALINFO3" id="twos" disabled="disabled><option value=" "></option><option value="Home button">Home button</option> <option value="Power button">Power button</option><option value="Mute switch">Mute switch</option><option value="volume button">Volume button</option></select> = <b>99.99$</b> 30$ in savings!<br>

    <input name="QUANTITY" type="hidden" value="1" /><br>
    <input type="image" src="./images/addtocart.png" align="center" name="BUY" value=" Add to cart " ALT="Add to Cart">
    </form>
```

this works on jsFiddle but not on my website or JSbin, witch gives error:

> $ is not defined Caused by line
>   (28/26):
>   $('input:radio[name="RADIOSELECTOR"]').change(function()
>   {

Also is there a way that when "select" gets disabled it automatically goes to first option? Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check to ensure the path to js/jquery.js was the correct location on in the server? Firebug will help you check that out if you're using Firefox. Failing that, are you using other JS libraries which might conflict with JQuery?

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jquery properly (is the path correct?)

I'm thinking this is the case, since it works in jsFiddle, which loads jQuery for you.

Comment: If you wrap your code in a closure and pass in `jQuery`, what do you get?

Comment: You forgot type="text/javascript" in jquery call, which is a required attribute, and don't work without in some browsers when in strict mode.

Comment: I added type="text/javascript" nothing, the path is correct, I even added path from ajax... i wraped in the path script also notihng, http://icuretech.com/revision/javascriptnotworking.html here the page so you can see that its not working. What else can I do ? Im pretty sure pathis good because I have other stuff using jquery no different page and its working.

Comment: ok got it to work, need to have one more thing done, when "select" is being disabled it has to change to first option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing your bindings before the dom is loaded.  You need to wrap your script in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

or the shorthand version of the same thing

```
$(function() { 
});
```

Comment: great that works ! is there a way that if somebody choose something from select and then press different radio, the disabled select will automatically go to first option ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.  If you have your selects always contain a first `<option>` with a value set to an empty string, then you can call `$('#selectId').val('');` and that should reset it to that first value.  Then just put that call inside the code that handles when your radio button click.

Comment: that works but not in IE, any changes need for IE ? Disabling works but it wont put it to first option. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

is not the correct path.  Try

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

or use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The fiddle works because it loads jQuery for you.

Answer (score 2):

@Rafal: It looks like you're missing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code
)};
```

Comment: great that works ! is there a way that if somebody choose something from select and then press different radio, the disabled "select" will automatically go to first option ?

Comment: @Rafal: You could remove `<option value=" "></option>` from both `<select>`s and it'll always show the first option. I suggest you also convert all your `onClick` logic to jQuery.